# php: when need to use self::method()?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public $prop1 = "I'm a class property!";

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was initiated!<br />';
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'The class "', __CLASS__, '" was destroyed.<br />';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        echo "Using the toString method: ";
        return $this->getProperty();
    }

    public function setProperty($newval)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $newval;
    }

    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this->prop1 . "<br />";
    }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // Call the parent class's constructor
        $this->newSubClass();
    }

    public function newSubClass()
    {
        echo "From a new subClass " . __CLASS__ . ".<br />";
    }
}

// Create a new object
$newobj = new MyOtherClass;


?>
```

Question:

If change `$this->newSubClass();` to `self::newSubClass();`, it also works, so when I need to use `$this->newSubClass();`, and when need to use `self::newSubClass();`?

Comment: self:: is use on static methods / $this is use on the obj itself.

Comment: and `self` is almost never what you mean, usually you want to use `static`. See info on [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `self::methodName` makes a static call to that method. You can't use `$this`, since you're not within an object's context.

[Try this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GXDrst):

```
class Test
{
    public static function dontCallMeStatic ()
    {
         $this->willGiveYouAnError = true;
    }
}

Test::dontCallMeStatic();
```

You should get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Using $this when not in object context in...

Answer (score 1):

From what I know if you use `->` in `$this->newSubClass();` it's used for accessing instance member of an object altough it can also access static member but such usage is discouraged.

then for this `::` in `self::newSubClass();` is usually used to access static members, but in general this symbol `::` can be used for [scope resolution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and it may have either a class name, parent, self, or (in PHP 5.3) static to its left.